# How to get the transaction ID in paypal node.js react?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, paypal

I am currently working on react js project where I need two main functionalities of Paypal one is to make payment and other is to make a refund on that payment ( sometimes partial refund on a subset of that payment).

I am following this sdk of the node.js implementation, https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NodeJS-SDK

but I want to extract the transaction ID and token and such details which I am not able to find in this SDK.

I am just getting the 
order ID
capture ID
refund ID but not the transaction ID , so how do I get that ?

also , I am suggested to use smart payment buttons but if I am using the smart payment buttons, I am able to perform the checkout operation,but getting different set of details like

payment ID ,
payment token and I don't know how to perform the refund for that payment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A capture ID ***is*** a transaction ID.

As discussed in comments elsewhere, the confusion was that the buyer/sender has its own transaction ID.

(For every PayPal transaction, the sender and the receiver each have their own transaction ID)